# Can I use a CTE data inside another CTE by joining both of them (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

**Requirement**
I want to get the first four hundred GROUP_ID's from a table(greater than input GROUP_ID), and in the same table against each GROUP_ID, there are two LOG_ID's out of which I want the lowest one. Once I get the lowest LOG_ID, I will use that LOG_ID to get the data from another table where it is a foreign key.

**APPROACH I USED**
First I have formed a subset of top 400 GROUP_ID's which are greater than input GROUP_ID's 
Then I used all the GROUP_IDs in my second subset where I will get the lowest LOG_ID against each GROUP_ID.
And finally, when I have the lowest LOG_ID, I used it to get the details from another table.

**QUERY USED**

```
WITH INIT AS (
SELECT GROUP_ID
    FROM PV_ADAPTER_LOG
    WHERE GROUP_ID > 2004141441192825
    AND ADAPTER_ID IN ('2568','2602')
    ORDER BY GROUP_ID
    FETCH FIRST 400 ROWS ONLY
)
,INIT2 AS (
SELECT MIN(L.LOG_ID) AS LOG_ID
    FROM PV_ADAPTER_LOG L
    JOIN INIT ON INIT.GROUP_ID =L.GROUP_ID
    GROUP BY L.GROUP_ID
)
SELECT  A.LOG_ID,A.OPER_SEQ AS CALL_SEQUENCE,A.GROUP_ID ,B.INTERFACE_ID,A.INSTRUCTION_NAME, B.ADAPTER_DETAIL AS XML_CONTENT,B.SEQ AS XML_SEQUENCE
    FROM INIT2
    JOIN PV_ADAPTER_LOG A ON A.LOG_ID=INIT2.LOG_ID
    JOIN PV_ADAPTER_LOG_DETAIL B ON B.LOG_ID=A.LOG_ID
```

Is my approach right or is there any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're looking for:

- Use `row_number` ordered by group to find the first 400 rows
- Use `row_number` partitioned by group and ordered by log to find the first log per group

Which is:

```
WITH INIT AS (
  SELECT P.*,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( 
      ORDER BY GROUP_ID 
    ) RN,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( 
      PARTITION BY GROUP_ID 
      ORDER BY LOG_ID
    ) MN
  FROM PV_ADAPTER_LOG p
  WHERE GROUP_ID > 2004141441192825
  AND ADAPTER_ID IN ('2568','2602')
)
 SELECT * FROM INIT
 WHERE  RN <= 400
 AND    MN = 1
```

Comment: Chris , so the ROW_NUMBER is assigned to each row after passing all the clause conditions?

Comment: Yes, the `select` clause is processed after the `where` clause. So `row_number` only operates on the rows where all the conditions are true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `analytical function` to get the first 400 groups and then record with min `log_id` per group in a single query as follows:

```
SELECT GROUP_ID, LOG_ID FROM
(SELECT P.GROUP_ID, P.LOG_ID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GROUP_ID) AS RNGRP, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GROUP_ID ORDER BY LOG_ID) AS RNLOG
  FROM PV_ADAPTER_LOG
 WHERE GROUP_ID > 2004141441192825
   AND ADAPTER_ID IN ('2568','2602'))
WHERE RNGRP <= 400 AND RNLOG = 1;
```

You can then use it wherever you want to use it. (In CTE or In Inner view)

Comment: Thanks Tejash , I read the analytic functions after this , And they are great will be using more often in future